# PowerShell script to open excel, wait for power query to refresh, and then save the file

Tags: excel, powershell, powerquery

I have an Excel that is using Power Query to get data from a API. What I would like to do is have this data update every day without having to open the excel myself. So I enabled the setting within excel to `Refresh data when opening the file`.

So I am trying to create a PowerShell script which open the excel, waits for the query to refresh, and then saves the excel. However I cant get it to wait update the query has refreshed before saving and closing.

**code:**

```
$Excel = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("G:\...\jmp-main-2020-07-17.xlsx")

While (($Workbook.Sheets | ForEach-Object {$_.QueryTables | ForEach-Object {if($_.QueryTable.Refreshing){$true}}}))
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

$Excel.Save()
$Excel.Close()
```

Comment: The Save() and Close() methods are on the Workbook object.  To exit out of Excel, you would use the Quit() method.

Answer (score 1):

I think your while loop is wrong. You should probably loop over the worksheets in the workbook and for each of them loop over the QueryTables. Then enter a while loop to wait until the `Refreshing` property turns `$false`

```
foreach ($sheet in $Workbook.Sheets) {
    $sheet.QueryTables | ForEach-Object {
        while ($_.QueryTable.Refreshing) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
    }
}
```

As aside: you should clear the COM object you have created after finishing with them to free memory:

```
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Are they automatically cleared after a script is finished?

Comment: @kutschkem Eventually yes, after all references to the objects are cleared (i.e. the counter is reset to 0). However, don't count on that being any time soon after finishing the script and exiting PowerShell..

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows Task Scheduler to open Excel file and VBA inside that Excel file to close it after data is refreshed.
No PowerShell script needed.

Comment: Can you edit this answer to provide more detail? This sounds like a useful approach, without further explanation of e.g., what your VBA looks like, or how you're triggering the chain of events from Windows Task Scheduler, it's unlikely to help future readers solve similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s example working with some small tweaks. Not sure why but the [QueryTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.querytables?view=vsto-2017) property did not have my collection of queries for the sheet however using the [ListObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.listobjects?view=vsto-2017) property did.

```
$file = "path\to\file.xlsx"
$Excel = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
foreach ($sheet in ($Workbook.Sheets)) {
    $sheet.ListObjects | ForEach-Object{$_.QueryTable.Refresh() | out-null}
    $sheet.ListObjects | ForEach-Object{
        while ($_.QueryTable.Refreshing) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
    }
}
```

And to properly save and exit out of the excel you would use

```
$Workbook.Save()
$Workbook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()
```